# I need to insert an image between text in aem6.0

Tags: aem

I need to insert a small image between text as below..

[Please click here to see the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iGHB.png)

Can I achieve this by using text and image component? If yes, how? Or any other way to achieve this?

Comment: if you do not need the icon to be configurable, just use css and implement a custom component that has a simple text and render that text on the html of the component by also having that icon css class there.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with image but that would require special handing in your script/jsp/htl.

In most of the cases these images are governed via CSS classes and not dragged and drop. You could use the plugins feature of richtext component to create custom styles and apply them to the text. Refer to the Adobe's document [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/operations/page-authoring/rich-text-editor.html#Plugins%20and%20their%20Features).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to add icon in the text configured via RTE. To achieve this you have to build custom plugin by using Coral/Granite UI. This [Link](http://experience-aem.blogspot.in/2015/09/aem-61-touch-ui-rich-text-editor-rte-browse-insert-image.html) will be helpful to develop same sort of functionality.